# Automatically prioritize seeding torrents with few peers

Tags: bittorrent, transmission

Is there a way to automatically prioritize torrents which don't have enough peers over torrents with a big swarm? For instance, is it possible to seed only torrents which have fewer than 10 peers? Or dynamically adjust priorities based on peer count? Or stop torrents with 10+ peers, and resume them once the peer count falls below 10? Or have an upload limit per torrent per day?

I primarily use [Transmission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_(BitTorrent_client)), but I could change the client if needed.

Comment: You will need to become developer of one of the open-source [BitTorrent clients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_BitTorrent_clients).

Comment: It seems that it exists at least one CLI. So you should be able to download the list of files with the number of seeders, to parse it (`awk`,`grep`,`sed`,`sort -n -k...`), and to decide which file to share and which one not... then put all as a script in `cron` or `anacron`... Good luck.

Comment: What do you try to achieve? Deciding to which peer you seed based on how many peers a peer has would probably not be a good metric.

Comment: @dirdi I'm trying to allocate more bandwidth to less active torrents, instead of popular torrents which would benefit very little from one more seed. I'm open to suggestions if you know a metric which works better than peer count.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Did you find a way to do this? I'm interested in it as well.

Comment: @an531 Nope. You might want to re-ask: questions without positively-voted answers cannot be used to close as duplicate, so at least your question will not be closed as a dupe of mine. And if you mention my question in yours (or in a comment under your question), I'll see a link to it here, which I would very much appreciate, especially if you're more lucky in terms of useful answers.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Every now and then I look up this issue to see if there is any progress. It doesn't seem to be the case now. You might want to check out the "Minimum number of available seeds" setting in uTorrent/Bittorrent. In theory, it should keep seeding till the specified number of seeds are available for the torrent. However, it doesn't really work for me - torrents with more than the specified value are still being seeded and some torrents with no seeds are ignored. You can also upvote the following qBittorrent issue: https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent/issues/9063

Comment: this is handled by the "torrent queueing" feature of libtorrent, see also [Prefer seeding torrents with a low number of available seeds](https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent/issues/9063) for qBittorrent

Answer (score -1):

While your motive seems honorable, I would not recommend to implement a modifications to the standard protocol as long as you did not evaluate all its effects in a testbed. Chances are that unexpected effects (even contradictory to the pursued goal) may occur.

E.g. a leecher that is interested in a particular tracker you are seeding to, may impersonate a big number of peers on all other trackers you are also seeding to, to disturb your metric and therefore mislead you to only seed to the tracker he is interested in.

The same attack could work if he wants to stop you from seeding to a particular tracker, by just impersonating a big number of peers for this tracker.

If one really want to implement a prioritization metric, I would rather base it on the the swarm-size and/or the seeder/leecher ratio.

Comment: So, how do I prioritize torrents with small swarm size or low seeder/leecher ratio?